# Optional array.map inside array.map

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, render

I have a menu, rendered due to an array.map BUT I want to have a submenu rendered too but I can not find the way of achieving this

for instance I have this correctly done

```
import React from 'react'

export const Menu = () => {


    const item = [
        'option1',
        'option2',
        'option3',
        'option4',
        'opction5',
    ]

    const subMenuItem = [
        '2.option1',
        '2.option2',
        '2.option3',
        '2.option4',
        '2.option5',
        '2.option6',
    ]
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                Hola
            </div>

            <ul>
                {
                    item.map((x, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>
                            {x}
                                                        
                        </li>
                    ))
                }

            </ul>
        </>
    )
}
```

but now I want to have a submenu on option2 mapping the subMenuItem  array if there is a condition in which some variable is equal to an option from item

something inside the above mapping like

```
if (x === 'option2') {
    <ul>
        subMenuItem.map((y,i)=>(
             <li key={i*1000}
                 {y}
             </li>

                         ))

      </ul>
```

something like that

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) `x !== 'opcion2' ? null : subMenuItem.map(...)`?

Comment: exactly, I have no problems doing the conditional redenering alone , but I can not find a correct way of achieving this inside the previous mapping

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `subMenu` field inside the menu item such as :

```
    const menu = [
        {"name": 'option1'},
        {"name": 'option2', "subMenu": [...]},
        {"name": 'option3'},
    ]
```

You can render conditionally:

```
return (
        <>
            <div>
                Hola
            </div>
            <ul>
                {
                    item.map((x, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>
                           <>
                            {x.name}
                            {x.subMenu && x.subMenu.map((subMenuItem, subIndex) => (
                               <li key ={index + subIndex}>
                                  {subMenuItem.name}
                               </li>
                            )}
                          </>                     
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        </>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'

export const Menu = () => {


const item = [
    'option1',
    'option2',
    'option3',
    'option4',
    'opction5',
]

const subMenuItem = [
    '2.option1',
    '2.option2',
    '2.option3',
    '2.option4',
    '2.option5',
    '2.option6',
]
return (
    <>
        <div>
            Hola
        </div>

        <ul>
            {
                item.map((x, index) => {
                    return ( <li key={index}>
                        {x}                         
                    </li>
                    {if (x === 'option2') {
                        <ul>
                             {
                               subMenuItem.map((y,i)=>(
                                 <li key={i*1000}>
                                            {y}
                                  </li>
                               ))
                             }

                  </ul>})
                })
            }

        </ul>
    </>
)
}
```

Try this

Comment: @MaykelContrerasCamacho if this worked for you, can you mark it as Answer. Thanks

Comment: I answer my own question though

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did

```
import React from 'react'

import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Menu = () => {

    const LI = styled.li`
    list-style: '-  ';
    `


    const item = [
        'option1',
        'option2',
        'option3',
        'option4',
        'option5',
    ]

    const subMenuItem = [
        '2.option1',
        '2.option2',
        '2.option3',
        '2.option4',
        '2.option5',
        '2.option6',
    ]
    return (
        <>

            <ul>
                {
                    item.map((x, index) => (
                        <LI key={index}>
                            {x}
                            <ul>
                                {(x === 'option2') &&
                                    subMenuItem.map((y, i) => (
                                        <li key={i * 1000}>
                                            {y}
                                        </li>
                                    ))

                                }
                            </ul>



                        </LI>
                    ))
                }

            </ul>
        </>
    )
}
```

just put the condition inside of it as it is...first time doing this , seems tricky though :P